# xmlstarlet: Querying and concatenating nested child elements with a single query

Tags: xml, parsing, xmlstarlet

i have an XML-file like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <project>
    <data>
        <modelType type="InstantMessage">
            <model type="InstantMessage" id="1" >
                <modelField name="From" type="Party">
                    <model type="Party" id="123456">
                        <field name="Identifier" type="String">
                            <value type="String">foo</value>
                        </field>
                    </model>
                </modelField>
                <multiModelField name="To" type="Party" />
                    <field name="Body" type="String">
                        <value type="String">bar</value>
                    </field>
                    <field name="TimeStamp" type="TimeStamp">
                        <value type="TimeStamp">2016-07-11 13:26:38+02:00</value>
                    </field>
            </model>
        </modelType>
    </data>
    </project>
```

I do want to produce following result with a single query:

```
foo|bar
```

I do not know how to access these fields when nested in different levels. I tried something like:

```
root@machine:/.../# xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /project/data/modelType/model -v "concat(/modelField/model/field/value'|'/field[@Body]/value)" file.xml
```

but I permanently got syntax errors by xmlstarlet. I do not understand how to use it from the [manual](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416). Does anyone know how to use xmlstarlet in this case?

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML file (as presented) is missing a close tag for `<project>`; that will cause a parsing error which will prevent `xmlstarlet` from being able to execute the query.

The query itself has a few problems: in

1. The syntax for the concat function is `concat(a,b,c)`; your invocation leaves out the commas.
2. Inside a match, xpaths are relative to the matched node. But the first element in the concat:

   ```
   /modelField/model/field/value
   ```

   is absolute, so it can only match from the root, which it doesn't. You need a relative expression:

   ```
   modelField/model/field/value
   ```

   or

   ```
   ./modelField/model/field/value
   ```

   And the last xpath:

   ```
   /field[@Body]/value
   ```

   won't be found because `field` is not the root element, and without the `/` it won't match either, because `field` is not an immediate child of the matched node. Here you could either spell out the path from the matched node, as above, or use `//` to select any child:

   ```
   .//field[@Body]/value
   ```
3. However, the specifier `[@Body]` is incorrect. As written, the selector succeeds if the element has an attribute named `Body`. You are trying to match an element with an attribute named `name` whose value is `Body`, which you would write as `[@name="Body"]`. The quotes are mandatory, which means that you need to use single quotes around the expression or backslash-escape the quotes.

Putting that all together, once you fix the XML file you could use:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T \
  -t -m /project/data/modelType/model \
     -v 'concat(modelField/model/field/value,"|",.//field[@name="Body"]/value)' \
  file.xml
```

The `concat` call is not really necessary since you can use several `-v` options, and `-o` to output a fixed string. You might find the following more readable:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T \
  -t -m '/project/data/modelType/model' \
     -v './/field[@name="Identifier"]/value' \
     -o '|' \
     -v './/field[@name="Body"]/value' \
  file.xml
```

Comment: Great explanation!!

Comment: This is such a great answer! The only thing is there are 2 missing quotes after `-m` and `[@name="Identifier"]/value`
here it is with the quotes added

`xmlstarlet sel -T \
  -t -m '/project/data/modelType/model' \
     -v './/field[@name="Identifier"]/value' \
     -o '|' \
     -v './/field[@name="Body"]/value' \
  file.xml`